# How to transport cargo with your own vehicles in X-COM apocalypse

Tags: x-com-apocalypse

Here is the deal, transtellar is hostile to me, and they are refusing to transport any goods between my bases, this includes any personel or alien artifacts I found. for agent equipment I know I can just transport the agent with a vehicle and equipment will just go along. but for science guys (which doesn't count as agent) and alian artifacts (which can't be equipped on agents or vehicles before research) I can't find any solution. is there any way to load them as cargo to our vehicles? I need this because my second base has large labs and I need alien artifacts to be transported there for research.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution. You just sell the alien artifact in the market from one base and buy on the other. Weapons are sold to megapol so they work like transtellar buying the alien artifact from one of your bases and "sell" it to another. the best part is it costs $0. Firing from one base and recruiting scientists from the other does not work though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, but I might remember this incorrectly, if Transtellar go hostile you can't transport people and some items about at all.

I ran into this problem and when I tried to recruit some more people and they never turned up, or a message said they couldn't get to their destination, I can't quite remember as is was several years ago!

Either way, Transtellar going hostile is one of the worse things that can happen in the game and I have always reloaded to an earlier save if it ever happens as it basically ruins the game if it happens and you *need* to move things from base to base.